# best practice for flavored build variants with gradle in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have an App that is produced for different brands.  Now I have two flavors, brand1 and brand2. The difference between brand1 and brand2 are only the resource files.

First I assumed I could set all shared data into my main path and the differences into the flavored path. But in this scenario my build failed, because resources in my main path are missing.

I would go on like this: set all resource differences between the brands in the main path as dummy data. The merge will do the rest for me.

In iOS I can set a build path for each build target. 
Is something like this possible with flavors? Or what is the best practice in this situation?

**[EDIT 2013 08 07]**

The problem in my case was that I created the app in eclipse and exported it to android studio. 
[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adt-dev/best%2420practice/adt-dev/Gn_Nw_MVn1s/EJcxZzOfAeYJ) the problem and solution is described more precisely.

Comment: try Gradle (fx in Android Studio i/o preview)

Comment: I work already with gradle and Android Studio (I edit my title).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to put everything shared (basically the a "vanilla" version of your app) as a libary project, including default resources.

Then you can create seperate "brand" projects that use the library project. Any resources you put in these will "overwrite" the library project resources.

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

I've done this for clients and it's worked quite well.

Comment: like in the comment above, I work with android studio and gradle.