# Using Flavors in gradle when importing project from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

For two days now im trying to create 2 different flavors in my Android app.
I imported my app to Android studio from Eclipse.
I created another 2 res folders (res_testing and res_distribution) and another 2 src folders (src_testing and src_distribution).
This is how my build.gradle looks like:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.6'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 17
  buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

  sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            packageName = 'com.comp.4u.testing'
        }
        flavor2 {
            packageName = 'com.comp.4u'
        }
    }
    android.sourceSets.flavor1{
        java.srcDirs = ['src_testing']
        resources.srcDirs = ['res_testing']
    }
    android.sourceSets.flavor2{
        java.srcDirs = ['src_distribution']
        resources.srcDirs = ['res_distribution']
    }
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
  }
}
```

But when i change the Build Varients, Although the app builds ok, still its using the same DataManager file as in the main src folder (Though i do get two different packages according to the names i gave them).

Its driving me crazy!!
I looked in 100 forums and posts, with no luck.

Each DataManager is using a different url to the server. This is the only thing i want.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321738/best-practice-for-flavored-build-variants-with-gradle-in-android-studio).

What happens when you remove the data from your main folder that is overriden in your flavors?
Do you get the error that the url is not found? If yes, than I think its the same error I get.

I solved this problem by creating a new project and copying all files to it.
I think that there are still some problems by exporting projects from eclipse and importing it to as.